# How to insert a link before php variable

Tags: php, html, file, hyperlink

When a user uploads a file to the database it displays filename.png in the table, I would like it to display a link EX: http://website.com/file.png in the table.

Here is an idea of how I started

```
   echo "<td>".<a href="http://website.com/">Download/</a>$sound['downloadlink']."</td>";
```

Orignal segment of code:

```
echo "<td>".$sound['downloadlink']."</td>";
```

Comment: you have asked enough questions to know how [php strings](https://php.net/language.types.string) work

Comment: Are you sure your images are in the root directory of your website? Maybe they belong to `http://www.website.com/images/file.png`.

Comment: Hello Jose, yes they are in an images folder but i am looking for just the general idea of how it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't right. You meann this?

```
echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/".$sound['downloadlink']."'>Download/</a></td>";
```

There is alot of examples of concatenation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 2):

How abt:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/" . $sound['downloadlink'] . "'>Download/</a></td>";
```

Comment: Hello Solid_Luffy, When I try this it will place the "filename.png" outside of the link and not part of it

Comment: The way I wrote it makes sure that filename.png is part of the href, but if you want your hyperlink to look like this `Download/filename.png`, then you can just break the string after "Download/" and add $sound['downloadlink'].

Answer (score 0):

Try not to echo HTML unless you have to. A better way is to echo variables inside HTML:

```
<td><a href="http://website.com/<?=$sound['downloadLink']?>">Download</a></td>
```

If you absolutely have to, you can do this:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/$sound[downloadLink]'>Download</a></td>";
```